# Openness and closeness in components.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

**Problem**  Each connected component of a space $X$ is closed. If $X$ has only
finitely many connected components, then each component of $X$ is also open.

I know that closure of a connected subspace of $X$ is connected but from this how we can say that each component of a space $X$ is closed? I didn't get this point.

**Edit**- The topologist’s since curve, $\overline{S}$, of Section $24$(Munkres Topology) is a space that has a single component(since it is connected) and two path-components. One path component is the curve  $S$ and the other is the vertical interval $V=0×[-1,1]$. **Note that $S$ open in $\overline{S}$ but not closed, While $V$ is closed but not open**.

Someone explain dark part.

Any hint or  help will be appreciable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, *path*-components need not be closed, as your example shows. But components are always closed, or the closure of a component would be a strictly larger connected set, contradicting its maximality.

And as $X$ is always a disjoint union of its components, if there are finitely many, each component's complement is the union of the finitely many *other* components, all of which are closed as we saw, and a finite union of closed sets is closed, so that complement is closed and the component is open.

Comment: Could you explain dark part?

Comment: @AmanPandey $\overline{S}$ is connected so has 1 component which is trivially open and closed too. $S$ is not a component of $\overline{S}$..

Answer (score 1):

Let $C$ be a connected component. $C\subseteq \overline{C}$ (closure of $C$) and $\overline{C}$ is also connected. Component is maximal connected set with respect to subset inclusion, so $\overline{C}=C$.